# When can standard numerical integration techniques be used to integrate a system with noise?

Tags: stochastic-processes, numerical-methods, stochastic-differential-equations, noise

I know that in order to solve a differential equation with white noise a stochastic numerical integration technique must be used. As I understand it, this is because the white noise has zero correlation time and therefore has unbounded variation. My question is supposing we have noise with a non-zero correlation time, under what conditions is it a good approximation to use standard (non stochastic) numerical integration techniques? To be more concrete, suppose I have an equation of the form
$$dy = f(y) dt + g(y)z dt $$
$$dz = -a z dt + b dW $$
where $z$ is colored noise (the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process) with the properties
$$\left< z(t) \right> = 0 ~~~~~~~\text{and}~~~~~~ \left< z(t) z(s) \right> = \frac{b^2}{2a}\exp(-a|t-s|)$$
where $\tau = a^{-1}$ is the correlation time. I know that the equation $dz = ...$ needs to be integrated using a stochastic integration method. The question is whether $dy = ...$ can be integrated using a deterministic method once $z_k, z_{k+1}, ...$ is known.

My guess would be that if I integrate using say a standard Runge-Kutta scheme with a time step $dt << \tau$ (say $dt < 5\tau$) then the results would be more or less the same as those obtained using stochastic numerical techniques. Is this correct? Is there some mathematical theorem which proves this?

Comment: I'm not really sure why you could use a deterministic technique in the first place. You want to simulate an SDE, so no matter what you do, you must use an appropriate discretization of your stochastic term. How would you integrate a stochastic integral using Runge-Kutta?

Comment: So there are plenty of examples online for how to generate a list of exponentially correlated colored noise values $z_{k},z_{k+1},...$. I was thinking I would just take that already existing code to obtain a ready made list of colored noise. Then I would add it to the end of my equation and integrate the entire equation as if it was a deterministic equation, using something more like the Euler method or Runge Kutta rather than the stochastic equivalent Euler-Maruyama. For example the Euler method would give $y_{k+1} = y_k + (f(y) + g(y)z_{k})dt$.

Comment: Ah, If that is what you want, then I would see no problem in plugging the sequence $z_k,...$ into your favorite scheme, but I wouldn't know any theorem to back that up from the top of my head. However, I think just directly simulating the coupled SDE using Eulear-Maruyama is just as easy.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I found a theorem called the Wong Zakai theorem. Essentially the idea is that if you have a regular approximation $w_n$ of the Wiener process then the equation $dx_n(t) = m(x_n(t),t)dt + \sigma(x_n(t),t)dw_n(t)$ converges in a Stratonovich sense to $dy(t) = m(y(t),t)dt + \frac{1}{2}\sigma(y(t),t)\frac{\partial \sigma(y(t),t)}{\partial y}dt + \sigma(y(t),t)dw(t)$. In other words there is an additional correction term. Wouldn't this mean that my results so far obtained are incorrect due to the additional correction term?

Comment: I think you are interpreting the WZ-theorem incorrect. The first equation (with $dx_n(t)$) is not the type of equation to which you apply the WZ-theorem. You should see this equation as $dx_n(t)=[m(x,t)+\sigma(x,t)B(t)]dt$, where $B(t)$ is some 'natural' approximation of $w(t)$. Then, in the limit, this equation will converge to $dy(t)=m(y(t),t)dt+\sigma(y(t),t)\circ dw(t)$. (If your interpretation were correct, you effectively showed that Euler-Maruhama converges to the Stratonovich interpretation).

Comment: So after thinking about it I also think that I slightly misunderstood the equation. Since the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck noise is of bounded variation it can be considered to be part of the $m(x_{n}(t), t)$ term, and so in this case $\sigma(x_{n}(t), t)dw_{n}(t) = 0$. It seems that the term $\sigma(x_{n}(t), t)dw_{n}(t)$ would not be equal to zero if I had some kind of unbounded noise which was deemed to be 'natural', although I'm not quite sure what 'natural' means if it doesn't mean noise with a non zero correlation time such as OU-noise.